# Infer property type given property key using Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I'm wondering how to go about inferring a property type given a property key. I'm not sure if this terminology is accurate, so I'll describe using an example (if I'm using the wrong or confusing terminology, please correct me).

Given the following types:

```
type Person = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

type Settable<Value> = {
    value: Value;
    setValue: (value: Value) => void;
}
```

I essentially want to end up with a type along the lines of the following, but would like to achieve this in a more programmatic, generic way:

```
type SettablePerson = {
    name: Settable<string>;
    age: Settable<number>;
}
```

I think I can achieve this with a [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) type, but I'm not sure how I would infer the correct property type for each key. So far I have:

```
type SettablePerson = Record<keyof Person, Settable<unknown>>;
```

Rather than each `Settable` having a type of `unknown`, I would like it to be the type of each property, such that the following should be valid:

```
let personName: string = 'john';
let personAge: number = 20;

const settablePerson: SettablePerson = {
    name: {
        value: personName,
        setValue: (value: string) => personName = value
    },
    age: {
        value: personAge,
        setValue: (value: number) => personAge = value
    },
}
```

Is this at all possible? Thanks in advance!

---

Edit:

The following is completely invalid Typescript, but may help illustrate my chain of thoughts on how to achieve this:

```
type SettablePerson2 = Record<keyof Person => key, Settable<typeof Person[key]>>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want can be done by using the [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html). Essentially, they allow to map through unions, keys and change the values:

```
// type SettablePerson = {
//   name: Settable<string>;
//   age: Settable<number>;
// }
type SettablePerson = {
  [K in keyof Person]: Settable<Person[K]>;
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwLACgopUBDAWwgC4pFh4BLVAcwG4CiSmriBXMgIwRt8AX2EFQkKAGUIwYCX4AbCAB4AaiSU8IAPkw52UAG5ad1TdojCiiOZfNQAFKasWzEAJSZ9x5PQATYTECAgB6MKhJaFl5RRU4JDQDPHwIomJybliFZTVaBmZdYXSOLmoc+LVUPkF4YvDIkQlwGLlchIQUdCxUogBtAGkoRigAawgQZAAzWC60AF0K9qrVRO6hhYbRYSA)